# Why when declaring setters and getters do I not need to declare a setter for an instance of an NSDate object?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

Following the big nerd ranch ios programming book and noticed getters and setters have been declared for all my instance variables apart from my dateCreated var:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface BNRItem : NSObject
{
    NSString *itemName;
    NSString *serialNumber;
    int valueInDollars;
    NSDate *dateCreated;
}

- (id)initWithItemName:(NSString *)name
        valueInDollars:(int)value
          serialNumber:(NSString *)sNumber;

- (void)setItemName:(NSString *)str;
- (NSString *)itemName;

- (void)setSerialNumber:(NSString *)str;
- (NSString *)serialNumber;

- (void)setValueInDollars:(int)i;
- (int)valueInDollars;

- (NSDate *)dateCreated;

@end
```

What's so special about NSDate that it doesn't need a setter declared?

Also in my implementation file how come I'm able to call dateCreated and store it in a variable with out a type specified?

How is it even being set? or called in the first place? I'm sure there is something going in the background. I've looked at the info for the NSDate object but I'm still quite confused.

```
//implementation of the designated initializer

- (id)initWithItemName:(NSString *)name
        valueInDollars:(int)value
          serialNumber:(NSString *)sNumber
{
    //call NSObject's (superclasses) initializer
    self = [super init];

    //give the new instance of bnritem some values for its instance variables
    [self setItemName:name];
    [self setValueInDollars:value];
    [self setSerialNumber:sNumber];
    dateCreated = [[NSDate alloc] init];

    //return the newly intialized object
    return self;
}
```

After trying to rush through this book I decided to start from scratch taking my time and making sure I understand everything 100% before moving. I've literally spent the whole day on this chapter and now this is a hurdle I can't seem to hurdle over.

Hope you can help.
Kind regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing special about `NSDate`. There is no setter method because the attribute is publicly read-only. It's value is set internally, once, and never changed. If you look at the name of the attribute then there is a good reason for this.

You don't need a setter. You can directly set the instance variable. Setters are a construct which allow you to add some structure around the management of your instance variables (like verifying the incoming value).

Comment: dateCreated is read-only because I've only declared a getter for it's instance variable in my interface file? If I declared a setter that would make it read/write? Also you're saying the only reason we use setters is if we need some more stuff to happen in the background while an instance variables value is being set e.g. add 100 to it before setting the value. If no management or additional work in the background isn't needed for the instance variables then getters/setters aren't needed? Unless I want to access the variable outside of the class and in that case I would create a getter?

Comment: Basically, yes. Not only, also to future proof for if you wanted to in the future and to show your intentions about what should be editable. You should do some reading about properties. Technically the accessor methods aren't required, they are a nicety to make intentions clear and safeguard functionality.

Comment: I prefer using properties but since starting this book I haven't come across a chapter that discusses using them yet. The book mentions that in later chapters they'll be introduced. I'm glad I now have an understanding about what's going on underneath @properties. Only slight issue is I'm using XCode 5, ios7 and this book focuses more on XCode 4, ios6. New release isn't coming out until december so I guess I'll run into a few issues going forward.

Comment: Your question relates to Objective-C, not Xcode / iOS versions really (which are UI and framework differences). Accessor methods and properties are language features. Properties are a shorthand form for declaring instance variables, accessor methods and the accessor method implementations all in one go.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your implementation BNRItem, you can access BNRItem variables directly. So `dateCreated = [[NSDate alloc] init]` is correct. You cannot do so outside your BNRItem implementation file.

Comment: So only when I need to access my instance variables outside of my BNRItem file would I need to use setters and getters? Even if I import the BNRItem file?

Comment: Since your getters and setters are declared in the interface, they are public. So you can access them outside BNRItem by importing BNRItem .h file. Your variables are also declared in the interface, but they are protected. Only in your subclass, you can access the variables directly.